# Kill Process in ffmpeg in c#

Tags: c#, cmd, ffmpeg, streaming

I'm using Process class to execute commands in ffmpeg like this:

```
string command = "/C ffmpeg -re -i test.mp4 -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:" + port.Text;
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = command;
process.Start();
```

this code streams video to network, but I want to stop streaming when I click on button

I used process.kill() but the process still streaming even if I closed application

How can I stop process in background or send ctrl+c to it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leading "/C" indicates that you start it via cmd.exe?
In that case process corresponds to cmd which in turn starts ffmpeg. Thus killing cmd doesn't kill ffmpeg.

```
string command = "-re -i test.mp4 -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:" + port.Text;
process.StartInfo.FileName ="ffmpeg";
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = command;
process.Start();
```

`process.Kill();` should work then.

Answer (score 1):

So I was going through the same trouble of starting and stopping ffmpeg process in my selenium Nunit test. After bit of struggle I was able to create a simple solution. Sending as "q" a input to the process window of ffmpeg gracefully stops the process and the video recording is not corrupt as well.
here is my c# code to start the ffmpeg and stop it after execution.

1. Create a bat file to start your ffmpeg (you will be calling this batfile from your c# code)
2. In you selenium test , create a recording class and 2 methods to start and stop the recording(in my case I was starting the bat file before all test as in calling the `executeScreenRecordingBatFile` method in `onetimesetup` attribute to start the recording and calling the `StopScreenRecording` method in `onetimeteardown` ) Sample code below.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace FunctionalTests
{
    public class Recording
    {        
        public static Process process;

        public static void executeScreenRecordingBatFile()
        {
            try
            {
                process = new Process();
                process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\StartScreenRecording.bat";
                process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;// this required to send input to the current process window.
                bool started =  process.Start();
                if (started==true) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Bat file started");                                                       
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace.ToString());
                throw;
            }
        }

        public static void StopScreenRecording() 
        {
            StreamWriter myStreamWriter = process.StandardInput; // this required to send StandardInput stream, nothing fancy 
            myStreamWriter.WriteLine("q"); //this will send q as an input to the ffmpeg process window making it stop , please cross check in task manager once if the ffmpeg is still running or closed.
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a method to kill ffmpeg process.

```js
private void KillAllFFMPEG()
{
   Process killFfmpeg = new Process();
   ProcessStartInfo taskkillStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
   {
     FileName = "taskkill",
       Arguments = "/F /IM ffmpeg.exe",
       UseShellExecute = false,
       CreateNoWindow = true
   };

   killFfmpeg.StartInfo = taskkillStartInfo;
   killFfmpeg.Start();
}
```

Just call it wherever you want.

> UPDATE 1

In order to kill just one instance of the FFMPEG process, we need to get it's PID first. When you define your ffmpeg process for streaming, define it in the global scope and use following command to get the PID after it is initialized.

```js
int myProcessId = FfmpegProcess.Id;
```

Then call the following

```js
private void KillFFMPEGByPID(int PID)
{
   Process killFfmpeg = new Process();
   ProcessStartInfo taskkillStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
   {
     FileName = "taskkill",
       Arguments = "/PID " + Convert.ToString(PID) + " /T",
       UseShellExecute = false,
       CreateNoWindow = true
   };

   killFfmpeg.StartInfo = taskkillStartInfo;
   killFfmpeg.Start();
}
```

This will kill only the process with the given PID. /T flag at the end of the argument determines that whole process tree will be killed.

Cheers

Comment: it works thanks but how can I modify it to kill one process by id ?

Comment: Note: This will kill any ffmpeg.exe, not only those started by you. Just in case you run other tools at the same time.

Comment: if we Kill FFmpeg processes it will close gently ? i mean what we doing in FFmpeg it will save as like crtl+c ?